# Animated text with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qpainter

Is it possible to draw an animated text with QPainter?
I only want to change color of text periodically.
If possible how to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new slot in which you will change variable storing color you use to paint text.
In the end of that slot you call

```
update();
```

to redraw widget.

To do it periodically you need also `QTimer` connected to that slot. 
In `paintEvent` you set color variable to pen or brush ( I don't remember which is used to draw text) used by `QPainter`.

That's all.